# What's the `.A` in `libobjc.A.dylib`

Tags: objective-c, c

Simple question, what's the `.A` in `libobjc.A.dylib`? Sorry for the simple question, but it isn't exactly easy to Google information about the letter "A" without Google thinking you're using it as the singular "a" as in "a cat."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is part of the name used to indicate a version of the library and allows multiple versions of the same library to be present. There is often an unadorned name which links to the current version, as is the case with `libobjc`:

```
$ ls -l libobjc.*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12937200  9 Jul  2016 libobjc.A.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel        15  7 Nov  2015 libobjc.dylib -> libobjc.A.dylib
```

This shows that `libobjc.dylib` is a symbolic link to `libobjc.A.dylib`.

As a different example consider `libgcc`:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel        17  7 Nov  2015 libgcc_s.1.dylib -> libSystem.B.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel        19 20 Dec  2016 libgcc_s.10.4.dylib -> libgcc_s.10.5.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     29480  2 Aug  2015 libgcc_s.10.5.dylib
```

Here there are three names, and two distinct versions, of the library available.

Software which requires a particular library version can link with the versioned name. Links are used when a later version is completely compatible with an earlier version, so software linking with the earlier version actually gets the later one.

All of this is only an issue with dynamic linking. With static linking the actual version of the library used during compilation is combined into the software binary and so there is no dependency on the library version(s) currently installed on the system.

Comment: But why not `libsystem.A.dylib`? Why `B`?

Comment: Oh so like how Frameworks have `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation`, this would be analogous to `libCoreFoundation.A.dylib`?

Comment: @l'L'l - I'm not sure I follow your question. The version bit can be *anything*; `libobjc` uses letters , `libgcc` numbers. If one version is completely compatible with another, or a generic name is desired for the latest version, a link may be used.

Comment: @CRD: How does this explain what `.A.dylib` is as opposed to `B.dylib`? And why wouldn't they have named `libsystem.B.dylib` as `libsystem.A.dylib` if it didn't have a direct relation to any `A.dylib`? Your answer covers how versioning works, but not in this particular case.

Comment: @lanza - Yes frameworks use a similar system inside their packages to allow multiple versions and label one current.

Comment: @l'L'l - the `A` and `B` versions are *probably* just different versions of the same library (`B` being newer). If there is an incompatibility between the two versions then both might be installed, if there isn't then one is installed as a link to the other. It is "probably" as this is only a naming convention, there's nothing to stop the `A` & `B` names being different libraries.

Comment: There is no `libsystem.A.dylib` though, so that would seem to indicate otherwise. If you look at the file `libmx.A.dylib` it does the opposite in terms of versioning as it uses `.A.dylib` as the symbolic link and has no physical library. This leads me to think that the `.A.dylib` is for correlation to `B.dylib` not so much as it is for versioning specifically.

Comment: @l'L'l - It's versioning, dug out a reference for you - it's buried somewhere in  [this Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryDesignGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002013-SW20)

Comment: @CRD: Thanks, although it still doesn't explain why `libsystem.B.dylib` exists and there's no `libsystem.A.dylib` present.

Comment: @l'L'l - Because there used to be but Apple encourage the use of the unadorned name and are quite happy to drop an `A` link to the current `B`, or something like that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is simply a naming convention to distinguish a dynamic library from it's symbolic link and the fact that any `.A.dylib` located within `/usr/lib` has the dependency of `libsystem.B.dylib`.

Using `ls` with grep shows all the `.A.dylib` files in `/usr/lib`:

```
$ ls -lat | grep A.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   6076144 Jul 14 23:41 libicucore.A.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel  14249664 Jul 14 23:41 libobjc.A.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     85136 Jul 14 21:29 libBSDPClient.A.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     32416 Jul 14 21:28 libDHCPServer.A.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    116352 Jul 14 21:27 libalias.A.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    497312 Jul 14 21:27 libpcap.A.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    530800 Mar 22 16:56 libtidy.A.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     84704 Mar 22 16:55 libipsec.A.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        21 Oct  1  2016 libBSDPClient.dylib -> libBSDPClient.A.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        21 Oct  1  2016 libDHCPServer.dylib -> libDHCPServer.A.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        16 Oct  1  2016 libalias.dylib -> libalias.A.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        18 Oct  1  2016 libicucore.dylib -> libicucore.A.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        16 Oct  1  2016 libipsec.dylib -> libipsec.A.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        15 Oct  1  2016 libmx.A.dylib -> libSystem.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        15 Oct  1  2016 libobjc.dylib -> libobjc.A.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        15 Oct  1  2016 libpcap.dylib -> libpcap.A.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        15 Oct  1  2016 libtidy.dylib -> libtidy.A.dylib
```

Now for `.B.dylib`:

```
$ ls -lat | grep B.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     60848 Jul 14 21:28 libSystem.B.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        17 Oct  1  2016 libSystem.dylib -> libSystem.B.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        17 Oct  1  2016 libgcc_s.1.dylib -> libSystem.B.dylib
```

Take any of the `.A.dylib` and check it's dependencies:

```
$ otool -L libobjc.A.dylib
libobjc.A.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.3.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.5.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)

$ otool -L libipsec.A.dylib
libipsec.A.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libipsec.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 300.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.0.0)

$ otool -L libicucore.A.dylib
libicucore.A.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 57.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.5.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)
...
```

Is it a dynamic library or a static library? `file` tells us that's it's a dynamic library all the way:

```
$ file libobjc.A.dylib
libobjc.A.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures: [x86_64: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64] [i386] [x86_64h]
libobjc.A.dylib (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
libobjc.A.dylib (for architecture i386):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
libobjc.A.dylib (for architecture x86_64h): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64h
```

It seems as though the logic here points to a means of identifying the dynamic libraries ( `A` ) which all have the common trait of depending on library ( `B` ).

Answer (score -2):

The `.A` files are static libraries. You can find more information on them [on the Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library).

They are collections of object files that are linked into the program during the linking phase of compilation, and are not relevant during runtime

Comment: Usually `.a` ( lowercase ) is a static library; and if it was a static library why would it have `.dylib` on the end, that's a dynamic library.

Comment: @l'L'l Actually, the .a.dylib gives you an option to link against both. Depending on what you want/need.

Comment: Is that documented someplace? Why wouldn't they have used a lowercase `.a`?

Comment: Any documentation on that?

Comment: `.a` is a static library. I've never seen `.A` outside of `libobjc`. That also leaves the question "What is the `.B` in `libsystem.B.dylib`?`